# ORA-00911: invalid character on oracle, but works with H2

Tags: database, eclipse, oracle, oracle-xe

I have the following SQL command, it works with H2 database, but when i try to run it on Oracle XE, it gets the " ORA-00911: invalid character " error.

```
create table EMPLOYEE (
EMPLOYEE_KEY       NUMBER(10) not null,
SALARY             NUMBER(10,2),
LAST_NAME          VARCHAR2(132),
FIRST_NAME         VARCHAR2(132),
SUPERVISOR_KEY     NUMBER(10),
constraint EMPLOYEE_PK primary key (EMPLOYEE_KEY)
);
create unique index EMPLOYEE_PK on EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_KEY);
```

Comment: Are you submitting two different SQL statements?  Or are you trying to run two different DDL commands at once?  If you are running them separately, which one causes an error?  If you are running them together, that won't work-- you'd need to run each DDL statement separately.  It also wouldn't make sense to create a unique index after creating the primary key-- creating the primary key will automatically create the index unless you already have an index in place that can support the primary key.

Comment: BTW, the first `DDL` already defines `EMPLOYEE_PK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With this example, when you created the primary key constraint, you also created an index with the same name as the index you are trying to create, `EMPLOYEE_PK`**.

Tom Kytes states on his [ask tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:36858373078604) site:

> A primary key or unique constraint is not guaranteed to create a new
>   index, nor is the index they create guaranteed to be a unique index. 
>   Therefore, if you desire a unique index to be created for query
>   performance issues, you should explicitly create one.

Oddly, enough when I run your DDL, I receive the ORA-00955 error and not the ORA-00911 (invalid character error).

Often times the ORA-00911 error occurs when one is copying from one editor to another and you copy some non-printable characters.

Below, I ran the first DDL statement provided and then I checked the indices created.  If you look closely, you will see that `EMPLOYEE_PK` index was created as a consequence of the primary key constraint which you created.

```
    SCOTT@dev> create table EMPLOYEE (
      2  EMPLOYEE_KEY       NUMBER(10) not null,
      3  SALARY             NUMBER(10,2),
      4  LAST_NAME          VARCHAR2(132),
      5  FIRST_NAME         VARCHAR2(132),
      6  SUPERVISOR_KEY     NUMBER(10),
      7  constraint EMPLOYEE_PK primary key (EMPLOYEE_KEY)
      8  );

    Table created.



    SCOTT@dev> SELECT ind.index_name,
  2    ind.index_type,
  3    ind.table_owner,
  4    ind.table_name
  5  FROM all_indexes ind
  6  JOIN all_ind_columns icol
  7  ON ind.owner       = icol.index_owner
  8  AND ind.table_name = icol.table_name
  9  AND ind.index_name = icol.index_name
 10  WHERE 1            = 1
 11  AND ind.table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
 12  /


    INDEX_NAME                     INDEX_TYPE                  TABLE_OWNER                    TABLE_NAME
    ============================== =========================== ============================== ==============================
    EMPLOYEE_PK                    NORMAL                      SCOTT                          EMPLOYEE
```

If you desire to create a unique index on `EMPLOYEE_KEY` separately, a number of approaches could be taken.  Here is one:

```
    --create the table

    SCOTT@dev> create table EMPLOYEE (
      2  EMPLOYEE_KEY       NUMBER(10) not null,
      3  SALARY             NUMBER(10,2),
      4  LAST_NAME          VARCHAR2(132),
      5  FIRST_NAME         VARCHAR2(132),
      6  SUPERVISOR_KEY     NUMBER(10)
      7  );

    Table created.

    --create the unique index

    SCOTT@dev> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX EMPLOYEE_PK ON EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_KEY);

    Index created.

    --add the primary key

    SCOTT@dev> alter table EMPLOYEE add
      2  constraint EMPLOYEE_PK primary key (EMPLOYEE_KEY)
      3  /

    Table altered.

SCOTT@dev> SELECT ind.index_name,
  2    ind.index_type,
  3    ind.table_owner,
  4    ind.table_name
  5  FROM all_indexes ind
  6  JOIN all_ind_columns icol
  7  ON ind.owner       = icol.index_owner
  8  AND ind.table_name = icol.table_name
  9  AND ind.index_name = icol.index_name
 10  WHERE 1            = 1
 11  AND ind.table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
 12  /

    INDEX_NAME                     INDEX_TYPE                  TABLE_OWNER                    TABLE_NAME
    ============================== =========================== ============================== ==============================
    EMPLOYEE_PK                    NORMAL                      SCOTT                          EMPLOYEE
    SCOTT@dev> 
 SCOTT@dev> SELECT cons.constraint_name
  2  FROM all_constraints cons
  3  JOIN all_cons_columns conc
  4  ON conc.table_name       = 'EMPLOYEE'
  5  AND cons.owner           = conc.owner
  6  AND cons.table_name      = conc.table_name
  7  WHERE 1                  = 1
  8  AND cons.constraint_name = conc.constraint_name
  9  /

    CONSTRAINT_NAME                
    =============================
    EMPLOYEE_PK
```

Answer (score 1):

I won' insist on the redundancy between a primary key and an unique index, but, to answer only to your question as it is titled:

> when i try to run it on Oracle XE, it gets the " ORA-00911: invalid character " error.

It chops on `;` as, as far as I know, you can only issue one SQL command at a time through the *"SQL Workshop > SQL Command"* page of Oracle application Express (you can send a PL/SQL bloc too)

*However* you can select your commands one by one and hit run. When there is a selection, only the sectioned part is executed. For example, in the following screen capture, only the first DDL statement will be executed by clicking on the *"run"* button:

[image: APEX Run button executes only selection]